# Does XPath will return a object other than String

Tags: xpath

I have map xml as below. I can retrieve a value using XPath but can I retrieve object instead?. For example I want Map object to be retured if I say /list/* . Is it possible to retrieve as object.

```
<list>
    <map>
        <val name="obj_type">USER</val>
        <val name="ret_name">user</val>
        <list name="attributes">
            <map>
                <val name="obj_type">USER_ID</val>
                <val name="ret_name">userID</val>
            </map>
            <map>
                <val name="obj_type">
                    USER_UsernamePasswordCredential
                </val>
                <list name="attributes">
                    <map>
                        <val name="obj_type">UNP_Username</val>
                        <val name="ret_name">UserName</val>
                    </map>
                    <map>
                        <val name="obj_type">UNP_Password</val>
                        <val name="ret_name">Password</val>
                    </map>
                </list>
            </map>
        </list>
    </map>
</list>
```

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction

> An expression is evaluated to yield an
>   object, which has one of the following
>   four basic types:
>
> - node-set (an unordered collection of    nodes without duplicates)
> - boolean (true or false)
> - number (a floating-point number)
> - string (a sequence of UCS characters)

This four basic types (plus others regarding update, order and completeness) are mapped by standar DOM XPath API. From http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult

> #### Definition group *XPathResultType*
>
> An integer indicating what type of result this is.
>
> If a specific `type` is specified,
>   then the result will be returned as
>   the corresponding type, using [XPath
>   type conversions](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#section-Expressions) where required
>   and possible.
>
> **Defined Constants**
>
> - `BOOLEAN_TYPE`
>     The result is a boolean    as defined by [XPath 1.0].
>     Document    modification does not
>     invalidate the    boolean, but may
>     mean that    reevaluation would not
>     yield the same    boolean.
> - `NUMBER_TYPE`
>     The result is a number as    defined by [XPath 1.0].
>     Document    modification does not
>     invalidate the    number, but may mean
>     that    reevaluation would not yield
>     the same    number.
> - `STRING_TYPE`
>     The result is a string as    defined by [XPath 1.0].
>     Document    modification does not
>     invalidate the    string, but may mean
>     that the string    no longer
>     corresponds to the current 
>     document.
> - `UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE`
>     The result is a node set as defined by
>     [XPath 1.0] that will be accessed as 
>     a snapshot list of nodes that may not 
>     be in a particular order. Document 
>     modification does not invalidate the 
>     snapshot but may mean that 
>     reevaluation would not yield the same 
>     snapshot and nodes in the snapshot 
>     may have been altered, moved, or 
>     removed from the document.

Comment: Can you suggest any similar apis which uses XPath.

Comment: @Kalyan: Do you mean a complain DOM Level 3 API? What's your language?

Answer (score 0):

It's only an object if you bind the data to an object instance.  Maybe you mean an XML element?  In any case, it's dependent on your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

the XPATH works only at the DOM level and return Nodes unstead of the real objects.

if you want to work with the real data types you can use some existing frameworks like [castor](http://www.castor.org/xml-framework.html) fo java, and for dotnet you can see this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XmlToClassAndBack.aspx).